# "Digital Nomad" in the United States?

Tags: usa, visa, digital-nomads

Is it possible to stay in the United States as a digital nomad?

Essentially, I'm a non-citizen and I don't have a green card.
My work is fully remote, and I'm getting paid within my citizenship country.
Will it be possible to live in the United States? What kind of visa allows that?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148153/discussion-on-question-by-whoisit-digital-nomad-in-the-united-states); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.